# Connection between router and server

Tags: router

Is it okay if I connect my router, which doesn't have Gigabit Ethernet ports but normal 100 bit ports; and one of my servers which has a Gigabit port? It seems connected but is it 100% stable and compatible?

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to run in this configuration. It will just run at the 100 bit connection speed rather than the Gigabit rated speed. You will have no issues with this setup beyond slower speeds.